# Correlate interdependent Event Streams with RX.Net

Tags: c#, .net, events, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have a class that has, among others, the three following events:

- DataSourceLoaded
- DataSourceUnloaded
- DataSourceFieldChanged

Right now I am using RX.Net in combination with its `.Throttle()`'ing functionality to slow down handling of burst / frequent incoming events as I only need to know IF something changed recently, not every single occurrence is relevant to me.

The part that I have a bit of problems with is that the underlying datasource may be added/removed at any time and the handler of the `DataSourceFieldChanged` event streams uses the datasource.

So basically the `DataSourceFieldChanged` event stream should only start once the `DataSourceLoaded` event occurred, stop immediately once a `DataSourceUnloaded` event occurred and re-start whenever the `DataSourceLoaded` reoccurred.. and so on.

After that `DataSourceUnloaded` event occurred, all 'throttled' `DataSourceFieldChanged` streams should however not trigger again.. as in: if a `DataSourceFieldChanged` event occurred *and* within the 500ms `.Throttle()` timespan a `DataSourceUnloaded` event occurred, the `DataSourceFieldChanged` event stream should not call the handler.

If a(nother) `DataSourceLoaded` event happens within or outside that previous 500ms `DataSourceFieldChanged` `.Throttle()` window also happens, they should also not trigger the `DataSourceFieldChanged` handler.

Is there any way to bring these three event streams in one combined RX.Net statement?

Moreover & ideally, IF the handler of `DataSourceFieldChanged` is already running while the `DataSourceUnloaded` event occurs, is it possible to pass along a `CancellationToken` into the `DataSourceFieldChanged` handler that got triggered beforehand and lets me cancel ongoing activities (so that I do not attempt to access the now gone datasource)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `DataSourceLoaded` and `DataSourceUnloaded` events are always raised in pairs:

```
from _ in DataSourceLoaded
from changed in DataSourceFieldChanged.Throttle(x).TakeUntil(DataSourceUnloaded)
select changed;
```

Read it as:

1. For each `DataSourceLoaded` event,
2. project throttled `DataSourceFieldChanged` events,
3. until a `DataSourceUnloaded` event.

Comment: Thanks Dave! And duh.. that was indeed way too easy - thought it would be more complex. One Q regarding cancellation of ongoing subscriptions / methods running for each 'changed' above: how would you signal cancellation whenever a DataSourceUnloaded event occurs WHILE the changed event is still being handled (basically the Q in the last paragraph in my original question)?

Comment: `OnNext` calls in Rx are serialized, so if `DataSourceUnloaded` fires while you're observing a call, then you simply won't receive another call. There's obviously an unavoidable race condition though. According to the Rx contract, it "will make a best effort attempt to stop all outstanding work". See §4.4 in the [Rx Design Guidelines](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205219).

Comment: To be clear, the Rx contract that I just quoted means that any subsequent or enqueued calls to `OnNext` will simply _not_ be observed. It doesn't abort the current call to `OnNext` or anything like that.

Comment: @JörgB. - it is fairly straight forward to send the observer of the current `DataSourceFieldChanged` a cancellation signal so it can cancel its current work after a `DataSourceUnloaded` event.  Pose it as a new SO question if you want to see some solutions.

Comment: Oh I see, he meant that the work that's already running in OnNext needs to be cancelled, not the work that's about to run. Agreed, a new Q is more apt since the answer is going to involve either external state or additional operators.

Comment: E.g., This `SelectMany` overload seems appropriate, assuming that he needs an Async function: 
`SelectMany<S, T, R>(IObservable<S> source, Func<S, CancellationToken, Task<T>> taskSelector, Func<S, T, R> resultSelector)`

Comment: @Brandon yes, that's what I originally meant - follow-up question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716527/cancel-rx-net-observers-ongoing-onnext-methods