# Cancel RX.Net Observer's ongoing OnNext methods

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive, reactive-programming, cancellation

As described in my original question (see [Correlate interdependent Event Streams with RX.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640548/correlate-interdependent-event-streams-with-rx-net/26647781)) I have an RX.net event stream that shall only call the observer's OnNext method as long as a certain other event is not triggered (basically 'Handle Change-* Events as long as the system is connected, pause while disconnected and re-start handling of the Change-* events once the system has re-connected).

However, while this works smoothly with new events, how would I cancel / signal cancellation to **ongoing** .OnNext() calls?

Comment: For clarification, the handling method is async/await-able and already takes a CancellationToken as parameter.. maybe it is possible to combine RX & this async method.

Comment: Can you post some code?  What are you passing in for a `CancellationToken` right now?

Comment: @Brandon will do later today, currently on the run and the project is on my machine at home. Right now I am merely handing in a default(CancellationToken) / CancellationToken.None as I was playing with but not convinced about using and external CancellationTokenSource field (that I'd trigger in the original Stream and re-create thereafter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your observer is already written to accept a `CancellationToken`, we can just modify your Rx stream to supply one along with the event data.  We'll use the Rx `CancellationDisposable` that we will dispose of whenever the stream is unsubscribed.

```
// Converts into a stream that supplies a `CancellationToken` that will be cancelled when the stream is unsubscribed
public static IObservable<Tuple<CancellationToken, T>> CancelOnUnsubscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return Observable.Using(
        () => new CancellationDisposable(),
        cts => source.Select(item => Tuple.Create(cts.Token, item)));
}
```

Putting this together with the solution from the other question:

```
DataSourceLoaded
    .SelectMany(_ => DataSourceFieldChanged
        .Throttle(x)
        .CancelOnUnsubscribe()
        .TakeUntil(DataSourceLoaded))
    .Subscribe(c => handler(c.Item1, c.Item2));
```

When the `TakeUntil` clause is triggered, it will unsubscribe from the `CancelOnUnsubscribe` observable, which will in turn dispose of the `CancellationDisposable` and cause the token to be cancelled.  Your observer can watch this token and stop its work when this happens.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I found your answer to a similiar Question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18477018/rx-and-tasks-cancel-running-task-when-new-task-is-spawned?rq=1) a bit more elegant to read though and combined it like this: https://gist.github.com/jbattermann/914d48f4011f0842a03b

Comment: Updated the gist & it does work completely now. Thanks Brandon, also for the hint regarding CancellationDisposable - didn't know that one, too.

Comment: Ah yeah that was for a slightly different problem than what you've posted here.  Your gist (and that solution) cancel the current worker task and start a new one whenever a new `DataSourceFieldChanged` event arrives.  Sounds like that's actually what you wanted though so good deal :)

Answer (score 0):

There's an async overload of `SelectMany`, though admittedly if similar overloads of `Do` existed it would be more semantically appropriate.

```
var subscription = 
  (from _ in DataSourceLoaded
   from __ in DataSourceFieldChanged
     .Throttle(x)
     .SelectMany(DataSourceFieldChangedAsync)
     .TakeUntil(DataSourceUnloaded)
   select Unit.Default);
  .Subscribe();  // Subscribing for side effects only.

...

async Task<Unit> DataSourceFieldChangedAsync(Field value, CancellationToken cancel);
```

This is nice because it ties cancellation to the *subscription* as well.

Calling either

```
subscription.Dispose()
```

or

```
DataSourceUnloaded.OnNext(x);
```

will cause the `CancellationToken` to be cancelled.

Comment: I created a work item. Alternative approaches are currently being discussed:
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/63#issuecomment-61631595

Comment: Thansk Dave. I've taken your and Brandon's solutions (more precisely, Brandon's answer to basically the same but earlier asked SO Question) and combined them into this: https://gist.github.com/jbattermann/914d48f4011f0842a03b

Comment: This works only 'almost' correctly though: IF a DataSourceFieldChanged is still being handled asynchronously and a DataSourceUnloaded happens in the meantime, the later would not trigger the cancellationToken for the WorkerTask(..) method - for obvious reasons, but not entirely "there", yet.

Comment: Alright, had a closer look at the logical arrangement of the Select/Switch and TakeUntil statements and the current Gist revision works entirely as expected \o/